# Postfix not respecting mysql alias domains

Tags: mysql, postfix, configuration, dovecot, alias

So the setup is using postfix, dovecot, postfixadmin and mysql. I have configured postfix admin to alias one domain, "name.co.uk" to "name.net", I see this in the database so there's no issue there. However, when sending mail to "name.co.uk" it is not sent to "name.net", I can see this by the fact it does not appear in the mailbox, and instead if put in the virtual mail directory for the old domain (that shouldn't exist in the first place!). Following it through the log files, it doesn't seem to take into account the alias at all.

```
#~ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 30720000
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = company.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.company.net/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.company.net/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.company.net/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domains_catchall_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domains_mailbox_maps.cf, mysql/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domains_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Then in the config files

```
#~ for name in /etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_*; do echo $name && cat $name; done
/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domains_catchall_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query  = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and alias.address = CONCAT('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'
/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domains_mailbox_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query = SELECT maildir FROM mailbox,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and mailbox.username = CONCAT('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND mailbox.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'
/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domains_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and alias.address = CONCAT('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'
/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
table = alias
select_field = goto
where_field = address
/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
table = domain
select_field = domain
where_field = domain
#additional_conditions = and backupmx = '0' and active = '1'
/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
table = mailbox
select_field = quota
where_field = username
#additional_conditions = and active = '1'
/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
table = mailbox
select_field = maildir
where_field = username
#additional_conditions = and active = '1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. Missing `:proxy` before `:mysql`.

New config files

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 30720000
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = company.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.company.net/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.company.net/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.company.net/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

and

```
/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
# mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
# handles catch-all settings of target-domain
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query  = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and alias.address = CONCAT('@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'

/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
# mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query = SELECT maildir FROM mailbox,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and mailbox.username = CONCAT('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND mailbox.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'

/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf
# mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and alias.address = CONCAT('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'

/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
# mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='%s' AND active = '1'
#expansion_limit = 100

/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
# mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query          = SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='%s' AND active = '1'
#query          = SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='%s'
#optional query to use when relaying for backup MX
#query           = SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='%s' AND backupmx = '0' AND active = '1'
#expansion_limit = 100

/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
# mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query = SELECT quota FROM mailbox WHERE username='%s' AND active = '1'

/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
# mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
user = mail_admin
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query           = SELECT maildir FROM mailbox WHERE username='%s' AND active = '1'
#expansion_limit = 100
```

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. For the benefit of the community, could you specify which line you edited in which file?

Comment: Every line containing `mysql:` now contains `proxy:mysql:`